# How to make a rectangular selection on an image in gimp using script-fu/scheme

Tags: scheme, gimp, script-fu

I try my hands on scripting with scheme in gimp, and started with something that should be easy: write a script that creates a selection on the upper half of the image.

Something like (set! sel (gimp-create-selection img)) and then work on that selection. But the above function does not exist, nor can I find functions to manipulate selections.

It looks like a selection is not an object type of its own but rather another channel of the image.

So how can I create and manipulate a selection on an image?
(Via script, ***not*** using the rectangular selection tool.)
Is there an overview of gimp data types somewhere?

I know common LISP, so scheme syntax is not the main problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(gimp-image-select-rectangle image operation x y width height)
```

In general, go to `Filters>Script-fu>Console`, and hit the "Browse..." button. Everything is documented there. Use the filter bar (I used `rect`) to locate possible candidates.

If you are into ancient computing systems, this functions used to be:

```
(gimp-rect-select image x y width height operation feather feather-radius)
```

(found the same way, marked "deprecated" in 2.8)

Comment: Error: eval: unbound variable: gimp-image-select-rectangle:  
looks like my version of gimp (2.6.6) is too old or it is missing some add-ons.

Comment: It works: (gimp-rect-select 19 0 0 300 400 0 FALSE 0)